# The custom HTTPHandler doesn't work on Windows 10 Home

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, httphandler

I created a custom HTTPHandler to process the data that is uploaded by the client by using a jQuery file upload.

When my app runs on Windows 10 Home, my custom HTTPHandler cannot be loaded.

My custom HTTP handler code is below:

```
public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private string fSource = "";

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var sheetName = "<select style='width:100%' id='ddlSheetName'></select>";
        var isUploaded = false;
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var files = context.Request.Files;
                var file = files[0];
                var fileName = "";
                //index = fileName.LastIndexOf('\\');
                //fileName = fileName.Substring(index+1, fileName.Length - index-1);
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                fileName = now.Year + "_" + now.Month + "_" + now.Day + "_" + now.Hour + "_" + now.Minute + "_" + now.Second + ".xlsx";
                var fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/" + fileName);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
                sheetName = GetSheetName(fileName);
                isUploaded = true;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { isUploaded = isUploaded, message = sheetName }));
    }
```

Here is the web.config being used

```
<configuration>
...
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="FileUploadHandler" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="NorthStar.FundManagerWeb._Transaction.FileUploadHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
.....
</configuration>
```

I tried the solutions in the questions:

- [Custom HTTP handler configuration fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727886/custom-http-handler-configuration-fail)
- [IIS 7.5 Can't load custom HTTP Handler with codebehind file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340635/iis-7-5-cant-load-custom-http-handler-with-codebehind-file)

But I cannot resolve the issue.